# BusyIndicator for navigating between pages

Tags: sapui5

I am quite new to SAPUI5 and still learning a lot.
Actually I am trying to set up a busydialog while navigating between two different views.

I already defined the busydialog and set it up on a press-Event after one hits the navigation button. The dialog is showing up, but Iam not really sure about the handling regarding the close event. I thought that onMatchedRoute could help me, but the dialog is not closing. My controller for the first page looks like:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/core/format/NumberFormat",
    "sap/m/BusyDialog"
], function(Controller, NumberFormat) {
    "use strict";
var BusyDialogGlobal;
    return Controller.extend("sap.turbo.ma.mc.controller.region.americas.AmFinance", {

onInit: function() {
        BusyDialogGlobal = new sap.m.BusyDialog("GlobalBusyDialog",{title:"Please wait. . . "});
onHomePress: function() {
        var oRouter = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
        oRouter.navTo("home");
        var getDialog = sap.ui.getCore().byId("GlobalBusyDialog");  
        getDialog.open();
```

This part is working. I am not sure about further process handling part to close the busydialog after the second page/view is loaded. Maybe someone has a small snippet or example that could help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining your 'BusyDialogGlobal' in a global scope. It is defined in the controller scope for this view. Therefore in your second view probably you cant access it.

Two approaches you can do here (in the order I think are better):

#### Option 1

Build all your controllers extending a custom 'Base Controller', this way you will have access to its functions from all the children controllers. To do so, create a normal controller, extending from sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller as you have done. Call it 'BaseController' for example and save it in your controllers folder. Then create all your view controllers extending from the BaseController. Something like this:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function (Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("mynamespace.controller.BaseController", {

       onInit: function(){
          this.BusyDialogGlobal = new sap.m.BusyDialog("GlobalBusyDialog",{title:"Please wait. . . "});
       },

       presentBusyDialog(){
          this.BusyDialogGlobal.open()
       }

       dismissBusyDialog(){
          this.BusyDialogGlobal.close()
       }

    }
});
```

Then in your view1.controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "mynamespace/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseController) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("mynamespace.controller.View1", {

       onNavigate: function(){
          //Do your navigation logic here
          //...
          this.presentBusyDialog();
       }
    }
});
```

And in your View2.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "mynamespace/controller/BaseController"
], function (BaseController) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("mynamespace.controller.View2", {

       onInit: function(){
          this.dismissBusyDialog();
       }
    }
});
```

#### Option 2

Easier but less elegant, just instantiate the busyDialog in your Component scope and retrieve it from that scope when needed.

To instantiate it from a view controller:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().BusyDialogGlobal = new sap.m.BusyDialog("GlobalBusyDialog",{title:"Please wait. . . "});
```

To open it from whatever view controller when needed:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().BusyDialogGlobal.open()
```

To close it from whatever view controller when needed:

```
this.getOwnerComponent().BusyDialogGlobal.close()
```

Comment: sorry, but option 2 isnt competely clear to me: i define var BusyDialogGlobal in the component.js file, correct? and then for each view, i have to instantiate the busydialog defined in the component.js file in each controller where i want to use the busydialog by getting the owner component, correct?

Comment: No. You need to close the same Dialog instance you have opened before to make it disappear. You instantiate your BusyDialog once. If you do it in your component scope, and save it into a variable in this scope, then you can retrieve this object whenever you want and call its methods 'open' and 'close'.

Comment: And you dont nedd to do 'var BusyDialogGlobal' in the component.js. Once you have the Component object (you get it with this.getOwnerComponent()) you can add new properties to it using 'dot notation'. For example: `Object = {} ; Object.property = 'myvalue'` -->

Comment: in this case you add a property called 'BusyDialogGlobal' to the component object, and save in it the whole BusyDialog instance. Then, you can get the 'BusyDialogGlobal' property from the component object whenever you want and call the methods of the BusyDialog instance saved in it

Comment: sorry, but iam not able to bring to work. looks like i sitll have a small understanding problem, thanks for your patience.i have the view1 controller where i declare the var BusyDialog; correct? after that, iam using the open method in the navigation method in view1 and the close method in view2. is that correct so far? do you may have a small snippet where it gets more clearer?